# ProcessBatchData not responding, uls error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

i am trying to use ProcessBatchData but it just not responding.
i created a sample console app with the following code

```
          using (SPSite site = new SPSite("siteurl"))
          {
              using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
              {
                  web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                  SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("folderurl");
                  SPDocumentLibrary docLib = folder.DocumentLibrary;
                  List<SPListItem> files = docLib.GetItems(new SPQuery() { Folder = folder, ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"" }).Cast<SPListItem>().ToList();

                  SPListItem f = files[0];

                  sb.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><ows:Batch OnError=\"Return\">");


                  sb.Append("<Method ID=\"1\">");
                  sb.Append("<SetList Scope=\"Request\">" + docLib.ID + "</SetList>");
                  sb.Append("<SetVar Name=\"ID\">" + f.ID + "</SetVar>");
                  sb.Append("<SetVar Name=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#Title\">It is Updated</SetVar>");
                  sb.Append("<SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Delete</SetVar>");
                  sb.Append("</Method>");


                  sb.Append("</ows:Batch>");

                  web.ProcessBatchData(sb.ToString());
                  web.Update();

              }
          }
```

nothing happens, not even an error. in the ULS i found this error:

"Batchmgr Method error. Errorcode: 0x7714c730. The file name you specified could not be used. It may be the name of an existing file or directory."

it seems that the Errorcode is randomly generated.

googling about that a bit is seems that this is theoretically an Access Denied error message, but i am running as the super user in my dev machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [Delete Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms461938(v=office.14).aspx) expects `owsfileref` parameter for a  **Document Library**

```
<Method ID="Text">
  <SetList Scope="Request">GUID</SetList>
  <SetVar Name="Cmd">Delete</SetVar>
  <SetVar Name="ID">Integer</SetVar>
  <SetVar Name="NextUsing">URL</SetVar>
  <SetVar Name="owsfileref">URL</SetVar>
</Method>
```

try to specify file url as demonstrated below:

```
string fileRef = f[SPBuiltInFieldId.FileRef].ToString();
sb.Append("<SetVar Name=\"owsfileref\">" +  fileRef +  "</SetVar>");
```